Postgres/Sqoop : ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
While Trying to import data with sqoop from a postgres table to hive a got the following error :
ERROR db.DBRecordReader: Top level exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" : 0xe9 0x70 0x61

The Following is the sqoop import :
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://@IP/db --table table --username user --password-file /path --hive-import --hive-table db.table --target-dir /path
-m 1

while searching for a solution a found that (Command : SHOW server_encoding):
------------------------
| server_encoding      |
------------------------
| SQL_ASCII            |
------------------------

and the client encoding is set to (Command : SHOW client_encoding):
------------------------
| client_encoding      |
------------------------
| UTF8                 |
------------------------

